# convert Dictionary into JSOn

Tags: json, c#-4.0, dictionary

i want to convert Dictionary into Json. the key is a string and the value is a ICollection of CompaignModel :

```
  IDictionary<string, ICollection<BuzzCompaignModel>>  BuzzCompaignByInterest ;
```

and here is what contain BuzzCompaign Model :

```
 public class BuzzCompaignModel
   {
      public long BuzzCompaignId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
   }
```

how can i convert BuzzCompaignByInterest into JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Json.NET and JsonConvert

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializingJSON.html

It doesn't matter dictionary or object are serialising to Json